# How to catch specific error message in javascript from backend

Tags: javascript

From backend I am getting specific error message during the post request. How may I get this message in javascript?

`catch(err => console.log('error', err.response.data))`
With this code I am getting just the type of the error, but I need the message which I throw from backend. F.ex `throw ConflictException("The name is already exist")`. I need get the following message "The name is already exist", not just the the type.

Comment: What do you use for backend? and when you look to the network tab on client side do you see the message there? If so, you can use it in JS.

Comment: As backend I am using Kotlin. I can't see it in network tab too. Can be that I have some mistaken in the backend?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
try {
 throw new Error('Custom Exception');
}
catch(err) {
 if(err.message){
 console.log('inside if & error message as follow : ',err.message);
 }else {
 console.log('inside else');
 console.log(err);
 }
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is for demonstration purpose, if it still not working then try

```
catch(err => console.log('error', err?.message));
```

Comment: I am getting just "error Conflict" without message which I need

Comment: ok, it means, above is giving you `error Conflict` which may be error string you are sending from backend?

Comment: From backend I ma sending the following one `throw ConflictException("The name is already exist")`

Comment: just edited my answer with demo. let us know if it works.

Comment: `try {
 throw new Error('Custom Exception');
}`
In your solution I should write message in frontend, but I have this message in backend. I want to get the message from backend

Comment: its just for replication purpose. so ideally you are manually throwing error & then catching with displaying of message.  Will it still no success? if no then show how you are using your web service call

Comment: Do you mean it should be done with the way how you wrote?Is it the right way?If yes then I can do how you suggest

Comment: yes please, so ideally, in your  try block call backend webservice, inside catch, use if else condition & display error from backed as I suggested. if it works please accept answer so that it will be helpful for community.

Comment: @Johny, also edited my answer with alternative , please have a  look

Comment: Thank you for your help. But stackoverflow doesnt allow me to accept because of the lack reputation

Comment: Can you please check now? I think you can able to accept & upvote answer.

Answer (score 0):

Caught errors generally have a message field stored at `error?.message` or if you using things like Axios or other API requests, error messages are generally at `error.response?.data?.message`!

Note: `?.` is an optional chaining to prevent other errors like `Can not read properties of undefined, reading x`

Comment: `error.response?.data?.message` - I am getting still undefined.
`error?.message`  - I am getting just the type of the error but not the message